# Xpath get nodes that do not have complete empty children

Tags: xpath

**Scenario (minified):**

```
<a>
  <Sections>
    <Section>
      <Title></Title>
      <Subject></Subject>
      <Body></Body>
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <Title/>
      <Subject/>
      <Body/>
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <Title>Hello</Title>
      <Subject></Subject>
      <Body></Body>
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <Title></Title>
      <Subject>I have a problem</Subject>
      <Body></Body>
    </Section>
  </Sections>
</a>
```

**Question:**

What XPath should I use to return a list of `<Section/>` nodes that have at least one child node not empty such that this is returned:

```
    <Section>
      <Title>Hello</Title>
      <Subject></Subject>
      <Body></Body>
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <Title></Title>
      <Subject>I have a problem</Subject>
      <Body></Body>
    </Section>
```

In other words, `<Section>` nodes with completely empty child nodes should be filtered out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.//Section[./*/node()]
```

i.e. look for `Section` elements that have children that have children (text nodes or element nodes). This may or may not work depending on your requirement for *empty child nodes*, and may therefore need refinement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XPath 2.0 you can use:

```
/a/Sections/Section[(true() = (for $i in * return has-children($i)))]
```

This checks for each child element if it has children and then checks if this is true for at least one children.

I am not sure if this can be achieved using XPath 1.0. The following works if there can be only text nodes as child elements:

```
/a/Sections/Section[not(. = "")]
```

However, this would not return the element if there is an empty element present, e.g. `<Title><test/></Title>`

Answer (score 0):

try this xpath:

```
//a/Sections/Section[count(*[.!='']) > 0]
```